# Smart Target 2014 with DD4T MVC.NET Application Not working

Tags: dd4t, smarttarget, ambient-data-framework

I am implementing SMartTarget on DD4T MVC.NET application as suggested here http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/dd4t-and-sdl-smarttarget-2014-integration

code is below

`ClaimStore claimStore = AmbientDataContext.CurrentClaimStore;
        var all = claimStore.GetAll();
        string str = all.Aggregate("", (current, VARIABLE) => current + VARIABLE.Key + " " + VARIABLE.Value);
        str = "Claim store values: " + str;
        string query = Tridion.SmartTarget.Utils.AmbientDataHelper.GetTriggers(claimStore);
        str = str + " query is:" + query.ToString();
        //ViewBag.query = str;
        //  throw new Exception(query + " something");
        if (claimStore == null) throw new Exception("claim store is null");
        Response.Write("Response is"+str);`

AmbientDataContext.CurrentClaimStore return the values however

AmbientDataHelper.GetTriggers(claimStore) returns empty string

similar question was posted here

[Smart Target 2014 with DD4T](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7810/smart-target-2014-with-dd4t)

However I am not able to find any solution, I also tried to fetch the promotion using .ASPX page and SmartTarget Tbbs which seems to be working fine.

Regards,
Sameer

Comment: First step would be setting the log level to DEBUG for SmartTarget and checking what it logs regarding the triggers. That should tell you where the problem lies (ADF is empty, or no triggers available, or no prefixes defined for those claims, etc.)